# Why i failed to fetch body from Api using retrofit in android. and it's return code 500 and it's return all my data in error body

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

I don't know why i received my all data inside the errorBody but i want to received data inside the body. am new in case of php please help me it's very important for me. it's return code 500 from backend you can check my log i add all the details here.

> Postman

```
[
    {
        "id": "15",
        "pathToFile": "1642584690_1590649486.mp4",
        "categoryId": "9"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "pathToFile": "1546153059_1590651415.mp4",
        "categoryId": "9"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "pathToFile": "https:/mozeloapp.in/viddo/UploadVideo/1590662957575.mp4",
        "categoryId": "9"
    }
]
```

> Php script

```
<?php
$getCategoryId=$_GET['categoryId'];
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","u781384687_sudhakarsinu","Prabhat@01","u781384687_vdimazaapp");

if($getCategoryId){
    $sql = "SELECT *from all_video where categoryId='$getCategoryId'";
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT *from all_video";
}


$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
$json_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

//  $json_array[] = $row;
array_push($json_array,
array(
    "id"=> $row['id'],
    "pathToFile"=> $row['pathToFile'],
    "categoryId" => $row['categoryId']));

}
echo  json_encode($json_array);
mysqli.close($connection);

?>
```

> Pojo class

```
package com.example.retrofitapi;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class VideoModel {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("pathToFile")
    @Expose
    private String pathToFile;
    @SerializedName("categoryId")
    @Expose
    private String categoryId;

    public VideoModel() {
    }

    public VideoModel(String id, String pathToFile, String categoryId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.pathToFile = pathToFile;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPathToFile() {
        return pathToFile;
    }

    public void setPathToFile(String pathToFile) {
        this.pathToFile = pathToFile;
    }

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }
}
```

> Api interface

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface VideoApi {
    String BASE_URL = "https://mozeloapp.in/";
    String FEED_URL = "viddo/retrivevideo.php";

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    @GET(FEED_URL)
    Call<List<VideoModel>>getVideo();
}
```

> ManiActivity

```
package com.example.retrofitapi;

import androidx.annotation.LongDef;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoApi videoApi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoApi = VideoApi.retrofit.create(VideoApi.class);
        Call<List<VideoModel>> call = videoApi.getVideo();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<VideoModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<VideoModel>> call, Response<List<VideoModel>> response) {
                try {
                    Log.d("VIDEOLINK", "onResponse: error code"+response.errorBody().string());
                    Log.d("VIDEOLINK", "onResponse: code "+response.code());
                    Log.d("VIDEOLINK", "onResponse: body "+response.body());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<VideoModel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Log cat

```
2020-05-28 17:24:07.772 12869-12869/com.example.retrofitapi D/VIDEOLINK: onResponse: error code[{"id":"15","pathToFile":"1642584690_1590649486.mp4","categoryId":"9"},{"id":"16","pathToFile":"1546153059_1590651415.mp4","categoryId":"9"},{"id":"17","pathToFile":"https:\/mozeloapp.in\/viddo\/UploadVideo\/1590662957575.mp4","categoryId":"9"}]
2020-05-28 17:24:07.772 12869-12869/com.example.retrofitapi D/VIDEOLINK: onResponse: code 500
2020-05-28 17:24:07.772 12869-12869/com.example.retrofitapi D/VIDEOLINK: onResponse: body null
```

Comment: Your api is returning error response code check why is it happening. The problem definitely on php side only.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you got 500 code that means the error coming from your backend server, So need to check your API thing between the android backend.